# Set cookie for div state (java script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

i have a function that controls two divs (collapse and collapse1). If one is set to style:block, other is style:none. The default style is `<div id="collapse1" style="display:none;">` and `<div id="collapse" style="display:block;">` This is also allways retrived on refresh or page load.

The function goes like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');

        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                toggle_switch.html('Show'); //change the button label to be 'Show'
                document.getElementById('collapse').style.display = "block";
            } else {
                toggle_switch.html('Hide'); //change the button label to be 'Hide'
                document.getElementById('collapse').style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So, how can i set the cookies for this function, so that if page gets refreshed, div style remains as selected, and doesnot go to default?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at [jQuery.Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), with this jQuery plugin you can easily set cookies.

Cookies can be set with just one line of code: `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');`.
Note that this will set the cookie for just the session, you can also set the cookie expiry date like this: `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 30 });` ("expires" is set in days).

To read the value of a cookie you can do this: `$.cookie('the_cookie');`, if the cookie does not exist it will return "**undefined**".

Hope this helps you on the way, let me know if this worked for you ;)!

Comment: Thank you for reply...but, i dont know how or where to insert $.cookie...Can you (or somebody else) give me some guidance? I really dont know much of js...TY